# Cauchy Integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

This was given to me as a $2$ part question. I was able to answer the $1$st part but the $2$nd part has me confused.

**a.** Let C be the unit circle $z=e^{i\theta}$ where $-\pi\le\theta\le\pi$. Use the Cauchy Integral Formula to evaluate $$\int_C\frac{e^{az}}{z}dz$$

I worked this out to be $2\pi i$. The $2$nd part is where I get lost.

**b.** Express the integral in terms of $\theta$ and find the values of $$\int_0^\pi e^{a\cos\theta }\cos\left(a\sin\theta\right)\ d\theta $$

I'm not sure where to go with part **b**.

Comment: Hint: find imaginary and real part of integral in a).

Answer (score 1):

You may parametrize the integral as $z=e^{i\theta}$ which makes the integral into:

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{ae^{i\theta}}}{e^{i\theta}}ie^{i\theta}d\theta=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{a\cos(\theta)+ia\sin(\theta)}id\theta=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{a\cos(\theta)}(\cos(a\sin(\theta))+i\sin(a\sin(\theta)))id\theta$$

$$=2i\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{a\cos(\theta)}\cos(a\sin(\theta))d\theta$$

Recall that from $(a)$ we have the value of $\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C}\frac{e^{az}}{z}dz$

Comment: I worked out that integral after looking at the hint above but I'm still confused as to where to go from there. I feel like its probably something simple but my brain just isn't connecting it.

Comment: Well the above shows you that: $2\pi i=\int_{C}\frac{e^{az}}{z}dz=2i\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{a\cos(\theta)}\cos(a\sin(\theta))d\theta$. So the integral is computed if I'm not mistaken. Just divide both sides by $2i$.

Comment: I'm not understanding where the 2i is coming from in the 2nd integral but I think I understand where you're going with the problem.

Comment: It's my fault you didn't notice the $i$. It came from parametrizing the circle and I let it stay close to the "$d\theta $". At the end I removed it from the integral. The $2$ came from the fact that $e^{a\cos(\theta)}\cos(a\sin(\theta))$ is an even function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I think I understand everything now.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you understand.